# Custom Events and Threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, events

I have two different projects and in one, I have a class that defines a custom event to fire under certain conditions:

```
  public delegate void ButtonHandler(object myObject,
                                           GuitarArgs myargs);

        public event ButtonHandler OnButtonPress;

... other stuff ...

  GuitarArgs myArgs = new GuitarArgs( guitarState );
                if(OnButtonPress!= null)
                     OnButtonPress(this, myArgs);
```

Then in another project I create an instance of this class and subscribe to this event:

```
Guitar.OnButtonPress += Guitar_OnButtonPress;
```

The event then fires properly, but it seems to be on a different thread, because when I try to access some UI elements, I get an error  : The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

The code throwing the error is:

```
 void Guitar_OnButtonPress(object myObject, Guitar.GuitarArgs myargs)
        {
            GuitarCheck(myargs.State);
        }

        private void GuitarCheck(GuitarState getState)
        {
                if (getState.green) 
                {
                    VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(guitarCanvas, null,
                                             MyHitTestResult,
                                             new GeometryHitTestParameters(
                                                 new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(1, 411, 88, 78))));
                }
}
```

What can I do to make this run?

Thank you.

Comment: similar problem to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403972/c-sharp-events-between-threads-executed-in-their-own-thread-how-to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using WinForms
`this.Invoke(() => GuitarCheck(myargs.State));`
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx)

If you are using WPF
`this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => GuitarCheck(myargs.State));`
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke.aspx)

Comment: You probably want BeginInvoke. When used improperly Invoke can lead to deadlock.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if your event handler is running on a non-UI thread and, if so, invoke it on the UI thread:

[How to update the GUI from another thread in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-gui-from-another-thread-in-c/661662#661662)

I would like to highlight the less-upvoted answer, which provides a very elegant approach using an extension method.  I use this in all of my WinForms projects (and use a variant in WPF/Silverlight projects)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3588137/141172

Answer (score 0):

So you have an event called `OnButtonPress` whos event handler is obviously executing on a thread that is not hosting `VisualTreeHelper`. The big question for me is...why? With a name like `OnButtonPress` it makes me think it should already be on the UI thread. Afterall, it is a button press right? So *why* is it executing on another thread to begin with?

Using a marshaling operation like `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` is fine as long as you are aware of why it is needed and what it accomplishes for you. But, you really need to take a step back and identify what all is going on that would cause you to *need* to use a marshaling operation in the first place. There may be a bigger issue here that you need to address.