# Why exception occured only in debug when a thread accesses the UI controls?

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I'm just curious about the thread and the UI Controls.

According to my test code, when I run the complied .exe file,the thread access the processbar wihout any issue. But when I debug the code, there's an InvalidOperationException. (Whatever the pooled thread or normal thread.)

So I know the thread is not allowed  to access the UI Control, but why it's ok when I run the .exe file. Is it an intended design?

PS.I know we can use backgroundworker to make things elegant.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(dothing);//use the pooled thread
    //Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.ThreadProcSafe));
    //t.Start();
}

private void dothing()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        progressBar2.Value = i;
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's possible that another thread is causing the exception while you're debugging. I don't pretend to know about how the debugger works on a lower level.. but it could be spawning an extra thread that is causing the race condition.

Comment: +1  good question, easy repro. Similar Q here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972727/why-is-cross-thread-operation-exception-not-thrown-while-running-exe-in-bin-debu

Comment: @JeremyThompson I'd say that pretty much answers this question :)

Comment: debuging UI behavior with breakpoints is usually tricky, since when you have a breakpoint the top window becomes your visual studio, and then when you return to your UI the update/refresh method gets called but if you were not debuggin that event will no be trigger. Is best to use any kind of log to a file to detect what is going on

Answer (score -5):

In my memory, you can't access UI Element in other thread but only in main thread. It's because of some multi-thread issue ( multi-access in same memory , asynchronous problem....etc.).
If you want to do what you want. You can use "delegate function" in C#.

Comment: I think you just told him what he said he already knows

Comment: I know we have some ways to access the UI. But my question is that why it's ok when I run the exe file without any exception.

Comment: Run the example, it should `NOT` work in Run-Time.

Comment: It works, right ? Because your program is not complex enough. And other reason is Processbar is a simply UI element.

Comment: If you use Viewtable something like that which contain read/write and both your thread / system thread / main thread will interact it. Your program will crash soon.

Comment: And I told that, c# doesn't allow you access UI through others thread. Its design is throw you a exception with that issue. If you switch to higher level of compiler setting ( a sensitive of error, I don't know how to say that ), your Release configure will throw you same exception , too.