# Cross-thread operation not valid in Debug mode, but in Release mode all is okay

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, runtime-error, task

Why I get an exception: "*InvalidOperationException: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control `lblText` accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on*" :when running application in debug mode?:

```
namespace testFormApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1() => InitializeComponent();

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblText.Click += (send, arg) => Need = false;
        }

        bool Need = true;

        private async void ButtonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Task.Run(async() =>
            {
                lblText.Text = "";
                while(Need)
                {
                    lblText.Text += ". ";
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

But same code in Release mode working without any problem. Why I'm getting this exception?

Comment: apart from the reason(i strongly doubt release mode not reproducible) and fix, above code is badly designed. can you tell us the idea behind the code?

Comment: iam trying to learn topic: ways to cancel task | now with boolean variable, after this i will check cancellationtoken

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the)

Comment: `Task.Run` will run your code on a thread pool thread which must not access UI elements. Just remove the `await Task.Run(async() =>`.

Comment: he have problem with code, but i have not problem with code. Code working normal in Release mode but in Debug mode i getting that error. Outside visual studio, if i go to folder of app and open my app, he will work normal cuz code not have problem. My english is bad sorry, idk how to explain my problem good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout Hans Passant's answer on this question, [Why is cross thread operation exception not thrown while running exe in bin\Debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972727/why-is-cross-thread-operation-exception-not-thrown-while-running-exe-in-bin-debu) he is saying cross-thread error checking is only enabled when a debugger is attached, also you can disable cross-thread errors check manually

Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;

Comment: so it looks like a compiler's walkaround to save poor programmers

Comment: This is answer. Thank you all.