# FolderBrowserDialog is closing my C# application automatically

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, folderbrowserdialog

I am developing my C# application in Visual C# Express 2010 and when i was opening the FolderBrowserDialog, it was opened fine and also i could able to get the folder name and files.

The same application (also i didn't changed any single line of code), i have opened in Visual Studio 2010 ultimate. While debugging the application, i didn't get any issues.

But, while opening the FolderBrowserDialog through application(when clicking Radio button), application has closing automatically without any error(i have the code in try-catch itself. not even getting any exception).

Here is my simple code which closing the application:

```
DialogResult getFolderDialogResult = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
```

while commenting the above, application is not closing.

Note:
i just added the openFileDialog before calling folderBrowserDialog, i wonder, it is working fine.

```
openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
DialogResult getFolderDialogResult = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
```

One more Note: i have created the new project and tried the FolderBrowserDialog. It is working fine :(

My Code:

```
        try
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Select Folder Radio Button CLicked", "Radio Button", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            string[] getFilesList = null;
            listBoxSelectSheetsMFR.DataSource = getFilesList;

            if (listBoxSelectSheetsMFR.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                listBoxSelectSheetsMFR.Items.Clear();
            }

            String tempString = "";
            ArrayList onlyFileNames = new ArrayList();
            String invalidFormat = "No";
            String folderPath = "";
            //Open Folder Selection Dialog
            DialogResult getFolderDialogResult = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();

            if (getFolderDialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                folderPath = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
                MessageBox.Show(folderPath, "Folder Path", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

                //Get All Files
                getFilesList = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath);

                for (int i = 0; i < getFilesList.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (!Path.GetExtension(getFilesList[i].ToString()).Equals(".xls"))
                    {
                        invalidFormat = "Yes";
                    }
                }

                if (invalidFormat.Equals("No"))
                {
                    panelSelectSheetsMFR.Visible = true;

                    //Enable the ListBox and load the filenames
                    for (int i = 0; i < getFilesList.Length; i++)
                    {
                        tempString = getFilesList[i].ToString().Replace(folderPath + "\\", "");
                        onlyFileNames.Add(tempString.Replace(".xls", ""));
                    }

                    //Adding Items into ListBox
                    listBoxSelectSheetsMFR.DataSource = onlyFileNames;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("One of file is having invalid Format. Please make sure all files \nshould be .xls format.", "Format Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show(getFilesList.Length.ToString(), "# of Files", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
        catch (Exception selectFolderExMsg)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(selectFolderExMsg.ToString(), "selectFolderRadioButtonFN", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
```

Comment: I would suggest first, that you clean out your bin directories and rebuild. failing that try building with a newer version of .net and see if that helps

Comment: show us how folderBrowserDialog1 is defined

Comment: use try and catch around it and see if anything pops up

Comment: clean out the Bin and rebuild is not helping. Also i tried with .Net 3.5 and .Net 4...nothing works...

Comment: @Flot2011
definition:
private System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDialog1;
i hope you are expecting this line....

Comment: @Prix: My code is already in try-catch block....no exceptions thrown....

Comment: @Pon: Note related to your question but I recommend using `foreach` loops instead of `for` loops.

Comment: here's another post for the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897076/folderbrowserdialog-crashes-the-application

Comment: Hey all, i tried the same code in different pc and it works fine...i think my laptop Visual studio having some problems...anyway i switched from laptop to PC....thanks to all :)

Comment: can you upload your project somewhere?

Comment: Maybe your VS is crashing due to insufficient memory of your hardware? I guess.. haha