# OpenFileDialog no show in different AppDomain

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain, openfiledialog

I have this simple code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Timers;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Xml;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
             ofd.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

which I compile when clicking a button with `CSharpCodeProvider`. I then load it into a new `AppDomain` and run the `Main` method, but the open file dialog is never shown. I know it is running as I have tested this.

Also trying to unload the domain results in an error.

If anymore information is needed just ask!

Comment: Perhaps you should paste the error unloading the domain gives.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the `AppDomain` you created doesn't have the `FileDialogPermission`. This means of course that trying to use an `OpenFileDialog` will fail. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.filedialogpermission.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Hi I added this code right after creating the `AppDomain`: `_compiledAssemblyDomain.PermissionSet.AddPermission(new FileDialogPermission(FileDialogPermissionAccess.OpenSave));`. But still nothing happens. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Well, I was thinking more of when you created it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130766.aspx (I'm not terribly familiar with .net > 3.5).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the namespace you're using reflects the type of application: [you cannot use OpenFileDialog just like that!](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharplanguage/thread/cd4795fa-8a7f-419b-bc46-462b35f3a35c)

Have you tried [adding [STAThread]](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharplanguage/thread/cd4795fa-8a7f-419b-bc46-462b35f3a35c) before the main function?

```
[STAThread]
public static void Main(string[] args)
```

Several components of the operating system, such as dialogs, use COM components, which to be communicated with, [need to have this attribute present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361033/what-does-stathread-do) in the entry point of the program.

Comment: Eh that thread did have a solution on to show the dialog; the only difference from my code to theirs was the [StaThread] attribute which I just tried adding but it didn't work (still does nothing)

Comment: So adding [STAThread] made no difference? What version of .NET are you using? And what version of Visual Studio?