# Different instancens in a thread, or threadpool?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool

I currently have a project that starts up a central logic class  (which uses some other .dll's to check on hardware or connect to the database). After that, a WPF form is started. This form uses the information of the central logic.

Currently, the application is being started like this:

```
public void StartTheWholeBunch()
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        applicationLogic = new ApplicationLogic();
        Application app = new Application();
        app.Run(new MainWindow(applicationLogic));
    });
    thread.IsBackground = true;
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start();
    thread.Join();
}
```

The MainWindow is one of the two WPF applications I want to use. So a second one will join in the fun o a later stage.

The current setup is working. Everything communicates with each other and stuff, no problems here. I was just wondering if the use of this `Thread` is correct. When I leave `applicationLogic = new ApplicationLogic();` out of the Thread, things are bound to go wrong (for example with creating MessageBox popups, the whole application will freeze here).

Should I keep everything in one thread here? Or is it a better practice to split everything up and/or create a Threadpool? How can I approach that the best way?

Comment: Hint: If you're starting a thread and immediately joining it, it's almost certain you don't need a separate thread.  The whole point of threads is to be able to (at least conceptually) do two separate things at once, and you kinda defeat that while you're waiting for the `Join()` to return.

Comment: @cHao The applicationLogic is supposed to run indefinately. I guess that means I should keep it all in this thread. I use `Join` because it'll shutdown otherwise somehow...

Comment: It probably shuts down because background threads don't keep the program alive.  (I didn't even realize you could `Join()` them, but eh.)  The app will only stick around as long as any *non*-background threads are running.

Comment: @cHao Ahhh... So if I don't set them as background threads, I don't need to use `Join`. Then I could also split the stuff up in multiple threads. Correct? I still wonder if both applications can reach out for each other's data...

Comment: It seems to me that if this setup is mostly working for you, then you could do it all in the main thread.  I'm not seeing where you really gain anything from forking it off.  But i don't have the whole picture; it does kinda depend on what this function is a part of.

Comment: @cHao Me neither, but I wondered by asking this question if there are some situations where splitting them up would be a better practice. Perhaps if you want to restart something? Or if the GUI crashes, you can shut down that thread without letting the other GUI and logic die?

Comment: Typically if you want to restart something, it's because it's misbehaving. Once a thread's reached that point, unless you built in a provably always-working self destruct button, you can't really trust it to shut down properly.  `Interrupt()` only works if the thread's blocked waiting for something in managed code, and `Abort()` can get extremely messy (leaving locks locked, etc). At that point, it's really better to just let the whole app die. If you want that kind of control, you kinda need each subprogram in its own app domain, so you can tear down the whole app domain and everything in it.

Comment: Course, if you do that, communication between the subprograms gets more complicated (and generally, slower).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **The applicationLogic is supposed to run indefinitely.**

I think you're mixing the need for a globally existent class instance and threads. You don't need a separate thread for this, you just need `ApplicationLogic` to be a Singleton.

```
public class ApplicationLogic
{
    private static ApplicationLogic _instance = new ApplicationLogic();
    public static ApplicationLogic Instance { get { return _instance; } }

    private ApplicationLogic() { }
}
```

Further, by performing an immediate `thread.Join();`, you're making the `Thread` a moot point. You don't need this thread, just start up the main form. And if you wanted to load another form, just do it, create a new instance and show it:

```
var otherForm = new OtherForm();
otherForm.Show();
```

and so now that we are making `ApplicationLogic` a `Singleton`, which is what you were doing with the other thread (kind of), you can just access it like this:

```
ApplicationLogic.Instance.DoSomething();
```

Comment: That's how I approached it at first. But when I try to run this, I get the error `The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.` when creating the form by `MainWindow newForm = new MainWindow(applicationLogic);`. That's why I created a Thread around it.

Comment: And that message is given to me when I'm not using any Thread, but just start up the main form. But I don't understand it very well yet so I might have messed something up.

Comment: A capital-S Singleton may be overkill here...and it tempts code to say `ApplicationLogic.Instance` rather than using the object it was given.  The superapp can keep an ApplicationLogic as a private field, and pass it to the `MainWindow` constructor as needed.

Comment: I just created a static ApplicationLogic instance. That should be enough to just pass along as parameter. As far as I know, by passing that instance to different classes, it's a pointer to the same instance and not different instances, correct?

Comment: @Joetjah: Yeah.  In .net, most object variables (everything but value-type variables) are references.  Grab a copy of the reference, and both copies refer to the same object.

Comment: @cHao Thought so :) It still leaves me with the previous error though, the only way I got it to work was by encapsulating everything in a thread...

Comment: I don't have VS handy... is there something in the project properties that lets you set the app's apartment mode?

Comment: @Joetjah, add the `[STAThread]` attribute above your method that starts up the application and that will fix the error. Here is a good article on **why it's necessary** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361033/what-does-stathread-do.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud I've placed that above my `StartTheWholeBunch` method. In that method, a new `MainWindow(applicationLogic)` is being created. I still get the error on the constructor of `MainWindow`. Doesn't everything created in the method annotated with `[STAThread]` automatically take over that utility? In that case, it doesn't seem to usefull then?

Comment: @Joetjah, is `StartTheWholeBunch` your startup method for the application? Check the `Properties` of the `Project`.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud You were right. It works now but everything now gets shut down after it all started up. I think I'm gonna stick with my old way...

Comment: @Joetjah, well what code do you have in the main method now? At most it should be the three lines that were inside of the `Thread`.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud The main method instantiates a class, in which `StartTheWholeBunch` is being called. Actually everything should be in that first class, but that aside, I get the feeling everything created in a method annotated with `[STAThread]` shares that same annotation. Is that so?

Comment: @Joetjah, did you read the link I provided that gives a good set of answers surrounding `[STAThread]`? It simply means that it starts up the Windows message pump on a single-apartment thread. This is necessary for Windows applications (unless of course you want to start everything up on its own thread like you did). It should be as simple as a method with `[STAThread]` and then application run with a window to receive messages.