# How can I paste url from clipboard to address bar in Chrome with Selenium c#?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have an alert box that shows a URL in the text input area and copies the link to the clipboard. I want to be able to open a new tab, and paste the URL into the address bar.

I have tried :

```
var generatedLink = System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetText();
_chromeDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(generatedLink);
```

*generatedLink returns ""*

I have also tried :

Attempt 1:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)_chromeDriver).ExecuteScript("window.open();");
List<String> tabs = new List<String>(_chromeDriver.WindowHandles);
_chromeDriver.SwitchTo().Window(tabs[1]);           
_chromeDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//body")).SendKeys(Keys.Control + "l");
_chromeDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//body")).SendKeys(Keys.Control + "v");
```

*SendKeys(Keys.Control + "l") does not select the address bar like it should*

*SendKeys(Keys.Control + "v") does not paste the text*

I know that the text is copied because when I debug the test, I can paste the copied text into Notepad without any problems.

The following is where the copying occurs:

```
const url = window.location.host + urlPattern.stringify(newUrlParameters) + queryString; 
  (navigator as any).clipboard.writeText(url) 
    .then(() => window.prompt('Link copied to clipboard!', url)) 
    .catch(() => window.prompt('Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter', url));
```

Comment: `generatedLink` shouldn't be empty if there's text on the clipboard. Can you set a breakpoint and verify your url is there?  Using your first set of code it works for me, I had to include the "http://" part of the url.  Using just "www.google.com" I get a `WebDriverException`, with "https://" in front of the url it works fine.

Comment: @gunnerone I set a breakpoint and am able to manually use Ctrl + V to paste the link into the address bar, but generatedLink is still empty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read Text from Clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35867427/read-text-from-clipboard)

Comment: Tried the similar question solution with no success

Answer (score 0):

To open a new tab with the *URL* copied from the *Clipboard* you'll need to reference the namespace **System.Windows.Forms** and you can use the following solution:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
// other code
string myURL = Clipboard.GetText()
((IJavaScriptExecutor)_chromeDriver).ExecuteScript("window.open('" + myURL +"');");
```

Comment: I have a reference to the namespace, as seen in the question above. But rather than returning the url from the clipboard, it is an empty string

Comment: If the _URL_ is at all copied to the clipboard this code block will cater to your need. Seems _URL_ is not copied to the _clip board_. Can you update the question with the relevant code how you are handling the _Alert Box_ to analyze if the _url_ is copied properly?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the url to the address bar, here are the solutions:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver).ExecuteScript("navigator.clipboard.readText().then(text => window.location.replace(text));");
```

or use [TextCopy package](https://github.com/CopyText/TextCopy):

```
Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(new TextCopy.Clipboard().GetText());
```