# Windows form application not closing

Tags: c#, winforms

I am making a Windows form app in c# and the process is never killed after I close the main form. The process sits in the background, taking up memory. I have tried many methods, such as Application.exit and Environment.exit, none of which have worked.

I have tried:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(Object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
```

And

```
static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
```

I have tried both methods using both Application.Exit and Environment.Exit

I just want a solution that kills the process upon closing the main form

### EDIT:

Upon closer inspection, this error only occurs when a button is pressed that switches to my project's second form using:

```
Form2 f = new Form2();
        f.Show();
        this.Hide();
```

Comment: Hiding your main window is the problem of course.  Just don't hide it, close it.  And use [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10769349/17034) to stop that from terminating your program.

Comment: Thanks it worked! Could you put this in an answer?

Comment: I already answered it, repeating answers gets me in trouble.  Just post it yourself, posting a link and a snippet should be good enough.  And mark the post as the answer to your question to close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it isn't already, you need to mark your main method with `[STAThread]` attribute (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1361048/1497128), like so --

```
        [STAThread]
        private static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
```

If it is, then make sure that...

- ... all foreground threads are being terminated before the form closes
- ... if you subscribe to `FormClosing` event then ensure you are not setting `Cancel = true`

Neither of your solutions are necessary, WinForm applications terminate the process when the main form is closed (assuming nothing else is blocking, such as another foreground thread). You can test this by creating a new WinForm project in Visual Studio, running it and closing the form.

Unless you are using specific logic to control when the application should exit, you definitely shouldn't need `Environment.Exit(0)` (mainly used for console apps) nor `Application.Exit()` (used with WinForm apps). Closing the form should do it, which can be done programmatically by calling `form.Close()`.

Comment: Upon closer inspection, this error only occurs when a button is pressed that switches to my project's second form.

Answer (score 3):

I have used:

```
Environment.Exit(0);
Application.Exit();
```

and it was working for me on a project of mine.

Answer (score 0):

when using a button click to open a new form use [USING](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6564/Understanding-the-using-statement-in-C)

```
 using (Form1 frm = new Form())
        {

            frm.ShowDialog();

        }
```