# Main Method with Windows Form Decorated with [STAThread]

Tags: c#

I have confused with a convention followed by `Main` method.. If talk about `Main` method of windows form application that is decorated with `[STAThread]` attribute.

And `Main` method of console application there is no such kind of attribute. So I want to know what is meant by this attribute and why we need it in `WinForm` and not in `Console`.

Comment: Did you try to search for explanations of it? Also without a search engine there are many question already shown in the Related column on this same page.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46544044/17034

Answer (score 2):

This attribute allows the app to communicate with COM components. Such as system dialogs and such.

A console app does not need this communication.